# Is li treated as another instance of p as far as pseudo-class allocations are concerned?

Tags: html, css

In trying to figure out the use of multiple pseudo-classes assignments (with an example that uses p and li content, I noticed that, sometimes, adding an extra line of text has the effect of 'breaking' the the pseudo class assignments.

e.g. in the code below, the extra line in section 2 breaks it (if it's commented out, then everything works great). but the extra line in section 1 does not break it. what gives? the only thing I can think of is perhaps that in the pseudo-class execution, the li is treated as a p (but in a sloppy way.... e.g. if I have an italic in that extra line then it still isn't coloured).

### CSS

```
/*For Section 1: First italic of all lines = colored */
div.ps1 li i:first-child{
    color: blue;
}

/*For Section 2: All italic of first paragraph = colored */    
div.ps2 p:first-child i {
    color: green;
}
```

### HTML

```
<h1>Section 1</h1>

<div class="ps1">
    <p> extra line</p>
    <li>What is <i> wrong </i>?   What is actually <i> wrong </i>? </li>
    <li>What is <i> wrong </i>?   What is actually <i> wrong </i>? </li>

</div>

<h1>Section 2</h1>
<div class="ps2">
    <li> extra line</li>        <!-- THIS EXTRA LINE --> 
    <p>What is <i> wrong </i>?   What is actually <i> wrong </i>? </p>
    <p>What is <i> wrong </i>?   What is actually <i> wrong </i>? </p>
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mok1yths/) is a fiddle of my code.

Comment: For starters your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Indeed...`li` can only be children of a `ul/ol`.

Comment: Isn't the `<i>` element deprecated for `<em>`?

Comment: Yes..and No. It depends on the actual content of the `i` or `em`and what it represents. If all that is required is italic text...a styled `span` would be the suitable choice.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child):

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

In your second section, the `p` is not the first child of `.ps2`.

```
div.ps2 p:first-child i
```

Is selecting the first `p` in `.ps2` **only** if it is the first child of `.ps2`.
If you want to select the first `p`, regardless of whether it is the first child or not, use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type).

[JSFiddle with `:first-of-type`](https://jsfiddle.net/shd6v728/)

On another note, your HTML is invalid, as you have list elements `<li>`'s outside of a `<ul>`.